# JavaScript single request to two different ports

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I'm testing a script where one function makes an HTTP request and is then called in another function.

The first function is:

```
export function getFeedData (sub) {
    if (getFeedId(sub) === 2) {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000').then((data) => JSON.parse(data));
    }
}
```

And the second is:

```
export function isDelay (sub, stop) {
    return getFeedData(sub).then((data) => {
        return data.entity.filter((entityObj) => {
            return entityObj.stop_time_update !== undefined;
        });
    }).then((newData) =>  {
        console.log(newData);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The reason they're two different functions is that the second will eventually be longer, and I wanted to separate everything out for the sake of simplicity and making my code a bit more declarative.

The tests for these functions currently look like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import { getFeedId, getFeedData, reverseStop, isDelay } from '../mocks/apiMock';

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('../mocks/MockData.json'));

it('returns json data', (done) => {
    app.listen(4000, function () {
        expect.assertions(2);
        return getFeedData('L').then((data) => {
            expect(data).toBeDefined();
            expect(data.header.gtfs_realtime_version).toBe('1.0');
        });
    });
    done();
});

it('returns either the delay or time until the next train' , (done) => {
    app.listen(4000, function () {
        isDelay('L', 'Lorimer St');
    });
    done();
});
```

That second test doesn't run because it's trying to listen on a port that's already occupied.

The solution I had in mind would be to pass `app.listen()` `0` as its first parameter so it listens on a random port. However, I don't know how I could get my axios request to request that specific port. Is there a way to do this? Or perhaps a better solution to my problem? Please be kind as this is my first real independent dive into creating node/express servers, and I'm trying my best to research problems on my own before posting here.

Comment: Can you either open up a second port or make one call and make the other when it is done?

Comment: I can't open a second one because there's only the one request - it's being called in each function. I don't know how to make one call and make the other when it's done. Do I do that by closing the server? I know express doesn't have `app.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one specific HTTP server port, e.g `:4000`.

Then, you should setup your HTTP server like this:

```js
const port = 4000;
let server
beforeAll((done) => {
  server = app.listen(port, () => {
    done();
  })
})

afterAll((done) => {
  server && server.close(done)
})

// Your test suites and test cases.
```

Then you can test your functions and they make HTTP requests to the same endpoint, e.g. `http://localhost:4000`.